# Eclipse error: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException and other errors

Tags: java, eclipse

So I keep running into this problem whenever I compile my code and i'm not sure why. Any sort of explanation would be great as to why i'm running into these errors.

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$152(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$50/14845382.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL: Invalid URL or resource not found
    at javafx.scene.image.Image.validateUrl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.image.Image.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at GUIs.GUI.start(GUI.java:39)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$159(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$53/16838191.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$172(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$46/18503843.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$170(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$48/11153519.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$171(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$47/2180324.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$145(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$36/3326003.run(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL or resource not found
    ... 17 more
Exception running application GUIs.GUI
```

The file compiles for my friend as we're collaborating on the same code, so i can see why Invalid URL shows as our pathing for the files could be different. But i can't make much sense of anything else in regards to the other errors.I have to note though that my friend is compiling it directly with the cmd prompt rather then using the eclipse IDE that I am using.

Comment: could you share code snippet ?

Comment: Are you sure the error is when "compiling" and not when "running" ? Have you checked the URL at `GUI.java:39` ?

Comment: `GUIs.GUI.start` at line 39 is calling `new javafx.scene.image.Image` with a bad URL argument - you need to work out why

Answer (score 0):

There is not much else to make sense of

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL or resource not found

is what you call a *root cause*. It's the only problem (so far).